# HttpException- Maximum Request length exceeded in Web service application

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-8

I got maximum length exceeded error in web service application , found that its due to input xml has more than 4Mb size and IIS is configured with default 4mb so changed the web config as below

Within system.web--5MB (xml is always less than 5MB)

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="5120" />
```

After that from SOAP UI, XML is processed but when calling through application , its not working.

Can anyone tell what will be the reason?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: can you check it out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded

Comment: Tried that but nothing worked,  do you have any idea if it works in SOAP UI , why not through application call?

Comment: Have you set `maxAllowedContentLength` in `web.config` too? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462(v=vs.90).aspx